# Outllook custom ribbon not showing

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am following a tutorial and the custom ribbon is not showing.
Could somebody help me? Please. I am new creating VSTO for Outlook

Tutorial link:
https://www.loginworks.com/blogs/create-vsto-add-outlook-2013-2016/

Answer (score 0):

Check if the add-in is enabled. 
File/option/Add-in/click on Go and see if your add-in is enable